# Грамотно ли говорить "камерный остров"?

Tags: стилистика

Верно ли с точки зрения стилистики и семантики русского языка говорить "камерный остров"? Если да, то какое значение имеет данное словосочетание?

Answer (score 1):

Нормальная стилистика и нормальная семантика.Значение слова Камерный по словарю Ушакова:

(от латин. camera - комната) (муз.). 1. Небольшой по объему, исполняемый соло или небольшим количеством исполнителей (о музыкальных произведениях). К камерной музыке относятся романсы, трио, квартеты и т. п.  || Исполняющий камерную музыку. Камерный певец (в противоп. оперному). 2. Предназначенный для небольшого круга слушателей, отличающийся интимными, домашними качествами.

Камерным, то есть маленьким, почти домашним, может быть и театр, и отель, и остров. Японские острова гордятся своей камерностью.

Comment: Да, но это все про музыку и певцов... Острова как-то не очень ложатся. Кстати, единственный реальный случай употребления обнаружен именно в отношении какого-то там японского островка. Явно маленького и заблудившегося в истории. Достаточно ли этого, чтобы назвать его "камерным", не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможное сочетание, но если для него нужно подобрать значение или угадать его, то оно точно не должно относиться к камерной музыке. Это может быть некогда безымянный островок, на котором организовали впоследствии прославившее его производство телевизионных или велосипедных камер (ср. "Вёсельная улица" - там занимались изготовлением вёсел). Либо это островок на территории исправительной колонии, который отвели под камеры-одиночки, в противоположность общей барачной схеме размещения сидельцев.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, "камера" есть комната, камерный певец с приятным тембром (но отнюдь не мощным голосом) может исполнить в ней специальные камерные произведения (опять-таки не оперу и не симфонию), произведения, рассчитанные на исполнение в небольшом помещении вроде комнаты; даже камерные концерты и камерные спектакли проходят непременно в маленьких залах, почти комнатах. 
Получается, что остров может быть камерным, если вас затопили соседи, а стол посреди комнаты возвышается тем самым островом :)
Мне это выражение кажется странным. Вычурным, как, например, "тщедушная книга", если она тонкая, небольшого формата...

Comment: Ответ сформулируйте, если вас не затруднит.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из значений слова "камерный": Отличающийся небольшими размерами; рассчитанный на небольшой круг людей. ([БАС](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))

В Нацкорпусе можно найти камерный музей, камерный городок и даже камерный бордель.

Так что "камерный остров" - вполне легитимно. Маленький, тихий островок.